# how to add bookmarks for txt file in java

Tags: java, swing, ebook-reader

I'm writing a ebook-reader program using java swing.
I read a txt file into a JTextArea.

```
JTextComponent.read(Reader in, Object desc).
```

Thanks to @Andrew Thompson, Now I can use caret position to jump to specific positon in JTextArea. But I still don't know how to update the caret while navigating the text so I can save it as bookmarks.

I wrote some code to show my problem:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class MyProblem extends JFrame {

    public MyProblem() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 60);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        String aLine = "Line number: ";
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            textArea.insert(aLine + i + newLine, textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }
        String problem = "When scrolling, how can set caret postion automatically on the first line of the viewport so I can save it?";
        textArea.append(problem);
        textArea.append(newLine);
        for (int i=21; i<39; i++) {
            textArea.insert(aLine + i + newLine, textArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        add(scrollPane);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyProblem().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends, what are you book marking? Pages, words, lines?

Comment: I'v paginated the file, and the page number can change depends on the size of the JTextArea, so I think I shoud book mark words.

Comment: Are you asking how to allow the user to jump to specific pages in the JTextArea, where "page length" is defined as the height of the JTextArea?

Comment: Note the bookmarks and other things associated with e-Book text are normally written to a separate file.

Comment: @VGR 'page length' is not a concept that fits well with e-books.  E.G. The text can be expanded (for easy reading) and the page numbers will be wrong.  E-books (at least Kindle) show no page number.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, page length can change denpends on the JTextArea's dimension. I use JScollPane' vertical scrollbar to count the page numbers. But I don't know how to save and/or jump to specific position in the JTextArea.

Comment: Look to methods like [`JTextComponent.setCaretPosition(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition%28int%29) & [`JComponent.scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).  Post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your attempt, and I might look at it further.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks, `JTextComponent.setCaretPosition(int)` can jump to specific position even though I set the JTextArea uneditable.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't know how to use `JComponent.scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle)`. Did you know a way to update the caret positon while i scroll the JTextArea so I can save the correct positon? And even though I know what an SSCCE is, I don't know how to write one to show my attemp.

Comment: *"And even though I know what an SSCCE is, I don't know how to write one to show my attemp."*  Now is a good time to learn.

Comment: I think you're asking how to save the current scroll position.  The best way is probably to save the text position corresponding to the top left corner of the visible area, using `textArea.viewToModel(textArea.getVisibleRect().getLocation())`.

Comment: Thanks to @VGR, I think now I can save model positon using `JtextComponent.viewToModel(Point)` and Jump to that position through `JComponen.scrollRectTovisible(Rectangle)`. I think I learn something and should learn more about these. Thanks for the directions.